# Múltiples imágenes en un Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Quisiera poder replicar un `Carousel` como el que se muestra en la imagen, pero `Bootstrap` solo me deja mostrar una imagen a la vez

[image: en la imagen se muestran varios elementos del Carousel en tipo lista]

Quisiera lograr lo que se muestra en la imagen, es decir, que se muestren 5 elementos fijos y con las flechas se desplazar y ver el total de elementos.

¿Es posible lograr algo como la imagen con `CSS` y `JavaScript`?

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="img/pdf.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <p>Archivo 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="img/pdf.png" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <p>Archivo 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="img/pdf.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <p>Archivo 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Agrega el código con el que probaste, así es más fácil ayudarte. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer exactamente el diseño que has mostrado tendrías que modificar un poco los elementos con tus propias clases, pero para hacer que el `Carousel` de `Bootstrap` trabaje con varios elementos, lo único que debes hacer es situar la cantidad de elementos que deseas ver en cada momento y con el diseño que decidas dentro de cada `carousel-item`. Por ejemplo, el siguiente código mostrará un `Carousel` con tres columnas dentro de cada `carousel-item`, dentro de cada columna podrías añadir lo que desearas:

```
<div class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">...</div>
                <div class="col">...</div>
                <div class="col">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">...</div>
                <div class="col">...</div>
                <div class="col">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Consulta el siguiente *snippet* para que notes cómo funcionaría:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">7</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">10</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">11</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">12</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">13</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">14</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-secondary py-4 text-white text-center">15</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible resolver este problema con las clases de bootstrap

```
class="carousel slide carousel-multi-item"
```

Tal como se ve en ejemplo del siguiente enlace:

https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/ascensus/135508

Comment: Hola Roberto, `carousel-multi-item` no es una clase de `Bootstrap`. En el ejemplo que has situado, lo que hace que haya varios elementos no es la clase `carousel-multi-item`, sino que el autor ha situado dentro de cada `item` del `Carousel`, una fila con columnas.